# Hybrid Mobile App Analytics

Tags: mobile, analytics, hybrid-mobile-app, web-analytics

I'm try to implement meaningful mobile app analytics. I thought this would be easy given the abundance of platforms out there, but I can't seem to find anything that meets my simple requirements.

My app is a PhoneGap app built using AngularJS, so I'm constrained to platforms with PhoneGap plugins (that are available for PhoneGap Build) or JavaScript Web SDKs.

I have a few simple technical requirements

- Track navigation (page views - user navigated to profile page)
- Track custom events (user hit cancel when prompted to enter credit card)
- Track custom user properties (dimensions - eg. Gender, Location, Age Range)

Most of the platforms seem to provide programmatic access to do this.

And a few simple functional requirements

- Drill down analysis of events - I want to see that user X (not with PII) hit cancel when prompted to enter a credit card, then I want to drill down to that session and see the flow of events and page navigation that occurred as well as user properties within that session...so for example I can see that they never viewed the "How it Works" page...and that they are male.
- Aggregate analysis of events - I want to see a count of all users (not with any kind of PII) that hit cancel when prompted to enter a credit card and then see how many of them were male, how many were from New York, and how many were...etc.

None of the platforms I've tried or look at seem to allow me to accomplish these functional requirements in a simple or usable way.

I've tried

- Google Analytics - a mammoth...of illegible meaningless metrics and numbers, but not what I need. Even with custom dimensions I can't seem to accomplish the functional requirements above. Also the data seems buggy...like sometimes events are missing custom dimensions reported with them...and sometimes they're not.
- Flurry - no custom dimensions
- Localytics - The websites is mindblowing slow to use and I can't find a view that gives me the functional information mentioned above.
- AppSee - only uploads when the user hits the home button...and seems buggy since it sometimes doesn't upload data at all

Any advice on a platform or SDK I can use to actually retrieve these important analytics would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Jeff any update on the platform or SDK you selected here.